# Ordered World Trade Center ticket but can’t make it

Tags: usa, new-york-city

I ordered a World Trade Center ticket for 2 PM on a weekday, but now I won’t be able to make it until later that day (let’s say 3:30PM). Is it possible to use that same ticket for later that day?

Comment: To be clear, are you referring to the observation deck in 1WTC (One World Observatory) or to the National September 11 Memorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the [One World Observatory](https://oneworldobservatory.com), in [the FAQ](https://oneworldobservatory.com/en-US/faq) it says:

> **What if I arrive later than my entry time?**
>
> Late arrivals will be
> accommodated based on capacity – you may be required to wait until the
> first possible open time slot. We strongly encourage you to arrive
> earlier than your scheduled time to avoid any delays.

Also, related to your question but not asked:

> **What is the refund policy? I never used my tickets.**
>
> There are no refunds or rain checks for your
> tickets – tickets must be used on the date/time listed on the ticket.
> However, if there is poor visibility, the See Forever Commitment
> ensures you can come on a good day.

Comment: The 9/11 museum also has timed tickets.

Comment: I confirm this is true after contacting customer service